# Is this true ?If $x_n \to 0$,then $n(x_{n+1} - x_{n}) \to 0$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, cauchy-sequences

If the **monotonic** real sequence $x_n \to 0$,then $$n(x_{n+1} -x_n) \to 0$$

---

1. In addition to some obvious examples(such as $\frac{1}{n^a},a>0$), I also verified some examples of sequences that converge very slowly.

   For example:
   $$n\Big(\frac{1}{\log(\log(n+1))} - \frac{1}{\log(\log(n))}\Big)\sim -\frac{1}{\log(n)\log(\log(n))^2}$$
2. I already know that the monotonicity condition is necessary, otherwise there would be a counterexample like this：
   $$n\Big(\frac{\sin(n+1)}{n+1} - \frac{\sin(n)}{n}\Big) \not \to 0$$

Comment: No it is not a counterexample,$n(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}) \sim -\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}} \to 0$

Comment: @MartinR: (retracted, should just give the [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2509422))

Comment: I think your expression for the meaning of $n(x_{n+1} -x_n) \not\to 0$ isn't right. It should be $\exists \varepsilon_0>0 s.t. \forall N> 0 \exists n>N s.t. n(x_{n+1} -x_n) \geq \varepsilon_0$. In other words, only some infinite subsequence needs to violate the bound..

Comment: @Alex K You are right,I found the problem in my proof.

Comment: Your examples $x_n = 1/n^\alpha$ and $x_n = 1/\log(\log(n))$ are of the form $x_n = f(n)$ with a *convex* decreasing function $f$. In that case $n(x_{n+1} -x_n) \to 0$ is true, I have added that as an addendum to my answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Counterexamples can be constructed as follows: Let $(b_n)$ be any sequence of non-negative real numbers such that

- $n b_n = 1$ for infinitely many $n$, and
- The series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$ is convergent.

Then
$$
 x_n = \sum_{k=n}^\infty b_k
$$
decreases to zero, and
$$
 n(x_{n+1}-x_n) = -n b_n = -1
$$
for infinitely many $n$.

Such sequences $(b_n)$ exist, for example
$$
 b_n = \begin{cases}
1/n & \text{ if  $n = k^2$ for some positive integer $k$} \\
0 & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$

---

*Addendum:* If $(x_n)$ is a *convex* decreasing sequence converging to zero, i.e. if additionally
$$
 x_{n+1} \le \frac 12 \bigl(x_{n}+ x_{n+2}\bigr)
$$
for all $n$ then
$$
 0 \le x_{n+1}-x_{n+2} \le x_{n} - x_{n+1}
$$
and therefore
$$
 0 \le n \bigl(x_{n} - x_{n+1}\bigr) \le 2 \sum_{k=\lfloor n/2 \rfloor}^n \bigl(x_k - x_{k+1} \bigr)
 = 2 \bigl(x_{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor} - x_{n+1}\bigr) \to 0
$$

That explains why $n \bigl(x_{n} - x_{n+1}\bigr) \to 0$ in your test cases.

(This corresponds to the fact that if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ is a convergent series with $(a_n)$ positive and decreasing then $n a_n \to 0$, see for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4603/42969).)

Answer (score 4):

For $n\ge1$, let $x_n:=2^{-\lceil\log_2n\rceil}$ (i.e., $x_n=2^{-k}$ if $2^{k-1}<n\le 2^k$ for some $k\ge0$). Then $x_n\searrow0$ and,
$$n(x_{n+1}-x_n)=\begin{cases}-\frac12,&\text{if $n$ is a power of $2$,}\\0,&\text{otherwise}.\end{cases}$$

Comment: You are right,this is a counterexample,but it should be -1 not $-\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Thanks! In fact, I meant to write $\lceil\cdot\rceil$, not $\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$. I corrected it.